# How do I choose what to parse from json?

Tags: python, json

I have managed to load the json file into python but can only get information from the headers, how can I get the information from the lists within them?
Sorry if this is very basic but I've had no luck on google as I don't know what to search. Thanks.

This is how I am importing the file and trying to print the name and link:

```
import json

with open('scrape.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data[0]:
        print('Name: ' + p[0])
        print('Website: ' + p[1])
```

And this is how my json file is formatted:

```
[
  {"product_name": ["title1"], "product_link": ["www.url1.com"]},
  {"product_name": ["title2"], "product_link": ["www.url2.com"]},
  {"product_name": ["title3"], "product_link": ["www.url3.com"]},
]
```

The output I get is

```
Name: p
Website: r
```

This info is from the first line and first 2 characters of "product_name"

The output I want is "title1" and "www.url1.com", I also then want to get the output from each line.

Comment: `data[0]['product_name']`?

Comment: Wow it was really that simple, thank you!

Comment: This isn't a JSON-specific question in any way. Once you do the `load()` your data is not JSON any more, it's just Python data; so you handle it the same way you'd handle any other Python data with the same shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the keys to get the values and since your values are lists, you can get the index 0 i.e. [0] to get the values:

```
with open('scrape.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data[0]:
        print('Name: ' + p["product_name"][0])
        print('Website: ' + p["product_link"][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this

```
with open('scrape.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data[0]:
        print('Name: ' + p["product_name"])
        print('Website: ' + p["product_link"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through a dictionary yields its keys, so:

```
for p in data[0]:
    print(p)
```

will print `"product_name"` and `"product_link"`.

Access the values by keys instead:

```
for product in data:
    print('Name:', product['product_name'][0])
    print('Link:', product['product_link'][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import json

with open('scrape.json') as json_file:  
    data = json.load(json_file)

    for d in data:
        print('Name: ' + d["product_name"][0])
        print('Website: ' + d["product_link"][0])
```

So how this works is:
You go through all the dictionaries inside your list and print values for keys`product_name` and `product_link` (you need to print first element of those valuues since they are lists).